# lxc container doesn't start because - lxc_conf - failed to setup the console

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, lxc

I use ubuntu 12.04 server with all updates
I was restarted lxc container by a command in shell: "reboot"

```
lxc version is: 1.0.0~alpha1.0+master~20130930-1830-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1

#uname -a
Linux zeus 3.5.0-34-generic #55~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 7 16:25:50 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And it was not started.

Log file of this lxc container is:

```
tail -f /var/log/lxc/redmine.log
```

```
      lxc-start 1380778101.754 ERROR    lxc_conf - failed to setup the console for 'redmine'
      lxc-start 1380778101.754 ERROR    lxc_start - failed to setup the container
      lxc-start 1380778101.755 ERROR    lxc_sync - invalid sequence number 1. expected 2
      lxc-start 1380778101.790 ERROR    lxc_start - failed to spawn 'redmine'
      lxc-start 1380778107.825 ERROR    lxc_conf - Read-only file system - error unlinking /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/dev/console
```

I create a new container, after that:

```
lxc-create -t ubuntu -n redmine-dev; And cannot start
```

Start it and log file is:

cat /var/log/lxc/redmine-dev.log 
      lxc-start 1380787652.125 ERROR    lxc_conf - No such file or directory - failed to mount '/sys/fs/pstore' on '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/sys/fs/pstore'

Comment: Excusme for previous not full comment, lxc container 'redmine-dev' started, despite the error: No such file or directory - failed to mount '/sys/fs/pstore'

Comment: Try this: ```sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils &&
sudo aa-complain /usr/bin/lxc-start```

Comment: I removed container that does not starting. Thank you for tip. I will use this in future. After this command I need to test a start. And If a start is OK, then switch to enforce mode via `sudo aa-enforce /usr/bin/lxc-start`?

Comment: @Willem can I ask you how did you related the error description with apparmor?.

Comment: I think app armor logs to sys log